# Confusion about the Limes of a recursive definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

i have a question how to generally get the limes of a recursive function. I have a recursive function defined as:

$$ a_1 = \frac{1}{4} $$
$$ a_{n+1} = a_n^2+\frac{1}{4}$$

i showed via induction that the function converges as it is monotone and $ \frac{1}{4} ≤ a_{n+1} ≤ \frac{1}{2} $

The second task is to calculate the limes of the given recursive definiton.

But isn't $\ \lim_{x\to\infty} a_n $ already given by the upper bound of $ \frac{1}{2} $?

If not, can somebody show me how to properly get the lim for this specific recursive definition?

It would be great to understand the problem further.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to demonstrate that the upper bound is the least upper bound. One way to solve for the limit is to pretend $a_{n+1}=a_n$ then solve for $a_n$. This will give you a quadradic which you can solve.

Comment: You know already that the limit L exists. Therefore, the limit of $a_{n+1} $ and that of $a_{n}$ is the same.  Apply it to both sides  in $a_{n+1} = a_n^2+\frac{1}{4}$ to get  $L=L^2+\frac{1}{4}$ and solve for L.

Comment: @CyclotomicField is that a general forumula for finding the limes of a recursive def? Thanks i thnk i know what you mean

Comment: @user376343 thanks i will try, that was my idea as will coming from the users comment

Comment: @JohnGam it's not a general formula for all recursive definitions but it often works for simple recursions like this one.

Comment: Alright so my solution is that $ a = \frac{1}{4} + a^2 =  \frac{1}{4}+ (\frac{1}{4})^2 =  \frac{1}{2} $. So $ \ \lim_{x\to\infty} a_n = \frac{1}{2} $ should be correct? Can anybody confirm this? Thanks!